# gcc C++ compiler - obj file creation non-deterministic?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, qnx, non-deterministic

**PROBLEM**

For a certain `.obj`, my compiler "toggles" the value of a byte between builds even when I don't change ***anything***. It's always the same byte position and it's always one of two values: `0x00` or `0x80`

[image]

**BACKGROUND**

I'm using QNX C++ compiler; it's `gcc`-based so just think of it as `gcc`.

My `make` command is:

```
C:\make421.exe all --trace --debug=vjm --jobs=16 --output-sync=recurse --print-directory --print-data-base
```

The `make` rule for this object lists files which are ALL contained within my top-level working folder.

It only depends on one `.cpp` file which doesn't change - I'm doing Beyond Compare on the entire `HMI_FORGF` folder which is where the artifacts are - and I'm also diffing the other folders that hold libraries.

ABSOLUTELY NOTHING IS CHANGING!

**QUESTION**

Why is one byte being toggled with no change in . . . ANYTHING?

Yes I'll also ask QNX but wanted to see if anyone has experienced something like this.

**UPDATE**

I did a diff of the [`objdump -xSsDg`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html) output but it's over 100MB is size so can't upload it (if anyone knows a site to host this let me know).

There are two sections in the diff that are different:

First section, left

```
Contents of section .ARM.exidx.text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE:
 0000 00000000 00000000                    ........
```

First section, right

```
Contents of section .ARM.exidx.text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE:
 0000 00000000 00000080                    ........
```

Second section, left

```
00000000 <.ARM.exidx.text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE>:
    ...
            0: R_ARM_PREL31 .text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE
            0: R_ARM_NONE   __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1
            4: R_ARM_PREL31 .ARM.extab.text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE
```

Second section, right:

```
00000000 <.ARM.exidx.text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE>:
   0:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
            0: R_ARM_PREL31 .text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE
            0: R_ARM_NONE   __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1
   4:   80000000    andhi   r0, r0, r0
            4: R_ARM_PREL31 .ARM.extab.text._ZN5QHashI7QStringiE11deleteNode2EPN9QHashData4NodeE
```

Comment: Not sure, but possibly the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)?

Comment: It looks that you compile with more than one job. This could give output in different sequences, which the compiler may treat differently.

Comment: @EmilioPastorMira what do you mean 'output in different sequences'? The compiler doesn't have memory: you invoke it, it takes your supplied info and then it goes away. No?

Comment: If it is GCC based, you can try compiling with `-save-temps` and check the assembly output to see clearer what is changing.

Comment: @rodrigo yup that's what I was getting ready to do!

Comment: @Adrian I was thinking more about the linker, but I forgot that you only look at one object, sorry.

Comment: I suppose it could be a compile time date/stamp/buld# macro that gets assigned to a literal value?

Comment: @Galik I'm trying to get `objdump` working on it so I can see what item is assigned to that address.

Comment: @Adrian Could you compile to assembly language and then compare the assembly outputs rather than the objects?

Comment: @FredLarson major update.

Comment: @rodrigo major update

Comment: @Galik major update